# Import css files from node modules in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, next.js

I am very new to `next.js`. Using it for the server side rendering of my application.

According to the documentation you can import css files from a static folder which should be in root directory but i want to import css from node_modules because i have extended bootstrap and created my own package.

Answer (score 14):

This is the solution you are probably looking for:

**3 simple steps:**

1. Install next-css plugin:

```
npm install --save @zeit/next-css
```

2. Create in your root directory next.config.js with the following content:

```
// next.config.js 
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }
})
```

3. Now you should be able to import styleshets from node_modules like this:

```
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

*Note: Using Next v 8+*

Other solutions are workarounds from before next-css was available, but as shown above, there is a simple and supported solution now.
It was provided by one of the core team members: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/ignoring-folders-files-specifically-fonts~4f68cfd5-d576-46b8-adc8-86e9d7ea0b1f

Comment: This is the correct answer. Unfortunately, I realized this > 10 minutes after I downvoted, and SO has a ridiculous rule preventing me from changing my vote unless it's edited.

Comment: I don't see the edit and am still unable to change my vote unfortunately. I proposed an edit as well in case yours isn't accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Since Nextjs 9.5.4, you can now import the css file directly from node_modules into the component where you need it (not required to be in _app.js). Just like this

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
```

See docs here for more info - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

Use @webdeb/next-styles instead of @zeit/next-css.Then you can normally import any node module style.

```
    const withStyles = require('@webdeb/next-styles')

    module.exports = withStyles({
      sass: true, // use .scss files
      modules: true, 
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Next.js 9.2, there is no more need to use `next-css` and `withCSS` or `withStyle`. Next.js natively handles CSS imports.
Since these may come with Webpack issues (see this issue: [Having trouble importing CSS in NextJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546601/having-trouble-importing-css-in-nextjs/62344944#62344944)), here's the way to configure loaders with webpack. In your terminal:

```sh
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

```sh
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

Then replace (or complete) your `next.config.js` file with the following:

```js
module.exports = {
    cssModules: true,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.node = {
            fs: "empty",
        };
        config.module.rules.push({
            use: [
                options.defaultLoaders.babel,
                {
                    loader: "url-loader?limit=100000",
                },
                {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                },
            ],
        });
        return config;
    },
};
```

Don't forget to remove any mention of `withCSS`, `withStyle` or `next-css` since they may cause some errors to happen.

Comment: This explains how to install some stuff, but doesn't explain how to use it. What does the require / import look like?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE :** if you have any problem importing normal css into your components follow [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-global-stylesheet) example.

beside that there is no difference.
if you are importing from static folder the address is something like:

`import stylesheet from '../static/css/index.css'`

now if you want to import css from a node module (for example rc-slider package), it will be:

`import rcstyle from 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';`

Comment: No you cant import in this way you need to look at next js documentation.

Comment: have a look at this issue https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/299#issuecomment-316400292

Comment: I thought you had no problem in importing css files.
now just use [wrap-in-js](https://github.com/davibe/babel-plugin-wrap-in-js) babel plugin and after importing css files inject them in your jsx as follows: `<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: importedcssfile}}/>
`

Comment: @dev123 you can also follow this example, it explains whatever you need to set up what I told you about : [example with global styles](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-global-stylesheet)

Answer (score 0):

For adding `node_modules/` prefix helped:

```
// Old
import "@splidejs/react-splide/dist/css/themes/splide-default.min.css";

// New
import "node_modules/@splidejs/react-splide/dist/css/themes/splide-default.min.css";
```

Comment: Do you have version numbers for the old or new code?