# Having trouble importing CSS in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having trouble import CSS file in Nextjs code. I have the following CSS file:

./src/components/Layouts.css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

In index.js, I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from "../src/hoc/Layout/Layout";
import Main from "../src/components/Main/Main";

const Index = () => (
   <Layout>
       <Main />
   </Layout>
);
export default Index
```

In Layout.js, I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Aux from '../Aux/Aux';
import './Layout.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../../components/Navigation/Header/Header';
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer";

class Layout extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

I get the error

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| a, abbr,
```

What I did:

In next-config.js, I added the following:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
    /* config options here */
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

|

Comment: Have you actually installed `@zeit/next-css`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `next-css` anymore (since Next 9.2).

To solve your required loader issue, install the following packages in your terminal:

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

Then replace (or complete) your `next.config.js` file with the following:

```js
module.exports = {
    cssModules: true,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.node = {
            fs: "empty",
        };
        config.module.rules.push({
            use: [
                options.defaultLoaders.babel,
                {
                    loader: "url-loader?limit=100000",
                },
                {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                },
            ],
        });
        return config;
    },
};
```

Don't forget to remove any mention of `withCSS` or `next-css`, or you may get an error!

Answer (score 0):

I think next-css only supports require. Try the following:

```
require('./Layout.css');
```

instead of

```
import './Layout.css';
```

At least this works in our codebase. Please let me know if this does not help.