# NextJS - Not importing styles from node modules in production

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, next.js

I'm using the react slick library for sliders and i have to import the styles from node_modules.

Thats the styles imports from my _app.js

```
require('slick-carousel/slick/slick.css');
require('slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css');
```

When i'm running the application locally, the styles are succesfully imported and the product list is like this.
[image: Product list with the imported styles - Running locally]

And in the production mode - https://amazon-next.lauradeveloper.com.br/
[image: Product list with the styles not been imported as expected]

I saw some people getting issues related to import styles from node_modules with NextJS. But i'm not understanding why it's working locally and not in the production mode.

My git repo: https://github.com/LauraBeatris/amazon-next

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255918/2947031

Comment: @SanketPhansekar This solution is deprecated since NextJS 9.2 where global CSS are supposed to be natively supported.
Did you find another solution to make it work @laura-beatris?

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen did u find any ?