# How to import SCSS on Component Level with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am coming from a CRA background and working my way through Next.js version 9.4.2

My project tree looks something like this :-

```
pages/
    _app.tsx
    index.tsx
components/
    Navbar/
        index.ts
        Navbar.tsx
        Navbar.scss
```

Inside my `Navbar.tsx` I have a statement `import './Navbar.scss';`

This gives me the following error :-

```
./src/components/Navbar/Navbar.scss
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to src/pages/_app.tsx.
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-global
Location: src/components/Navbar/Navbar.tsx
```

The error, as mentioned, goes away if I move the `import Navbar.scss` statement to `pages/_app.tsx`

I know I can switch to `Navbar.module.scss`, but I don't want to go down the route of modular scss as I expect my scss to get complex I would like to stick to the manner in which I write my scss and not keep finding work arounds to issues that might arise later. I am open to being convinced here but I have not found good read ups on this to choose it as my path.

So by the looks if it, I am stuck with importing all `<component>.scss` files in `_app.tsx`. This will leave me with a long list of `<component>.scss` imports in my `_app.tsx` and I will also be left with a lot of `<component>.scss` files for Components that might conditionally not render.

What are my options here ?

Comment: A solution that seems to solve this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192088/import-css-files-from-node-modules-in-next-js#answer-60847860

Comment: What solution did you end up going with?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach I used `import styles from <component>.module.scss`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Navbar.scss` file is not named properly.

Let's say your stylesheet contains something like...

```
$color: red;

.someclassselector {
    color: $color;
}
```

Component stylesheet files have to be named in the following convention for `next.js` to compile them as addressed in next's [css getting started guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)

```
<TheComponent>.module.scss
```

be imported like this:

```js
import styles from './<MyComponent>.module.scss>';
```

and be applied to the component like this:

```
<TheComponent className={styles.someclassselector} />
```

Not really an expert but it seems that you should stick to `class` selectors as `global` selectors can only be declared if you import them in `pages/_app.js`. You may name a `main.scss` file to use `Global` or `Tag Element` selectors like `h1 {}`,`h2{}`, `* {}`, etc.